# FFmpeg - Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, conversion

What's wrong about this command?
I want to convert a *.avi* format video to *"video=h.264/.mp4, audio=.mp3"* video.

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\video.avi" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -qp 0 -pass 2 -c:a mp3 -b:a 192k "C:\video.mp4"
```

Output :

```
ffmpeg version N-75550-g23acb98 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavcodec     57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavformat    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6.  8.100 /  6.  8.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, avi, from 'video.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2540/release)
  Duration: 00:24:39.31, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1757 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1280x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1491 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
[libx264 @ 00000000050647a0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000000050647a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 00000000050647a0] constant rate-factor is incompatible with 2pass.
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2540/release)
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 0:0, 23.98 fps
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.3.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 0 channels, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.3.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `Error while opening encoder`

This message states which output stream is having an issue. In your case it is `#0:0` which, according to the console output, is the video.

Also, when you get this message you can usually scroll up to see another error message that is more specific. In your output it is:

```
[libx264 @ 00000000050647a0] constant rate-factor is incompatible with 2pass.
```

### The cause

Your command is using two rate control methods: `-qp` and `-b:v`. These are mutually exclusive, and `-qp` is not compatible with 2pass.

### How to fix

- Don't use 2pass, or
- Don't use `-qp` or `-crf` with 2pass (unless you know what you're doing)

2pass does not mean better quality. 2pass is mostly used when you are trying to output within a specific file size limitation.

### What you requested

> 1. "What I want is to re-encode the video that keep the original quality"

You can't keep the "original quality" with a lossy encoder. You'll have to use lossless settings:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -qp 0 output.mp4
```

The output file will be huge, but lossless.

> 2. "Could you make changes on the command to re-encode the video that keep quality as much as possible"

A `-crf` value of around 18 is considered to be roughly "visually lossless". It is not technically lossless, but will likely appear to be so depending on your input and how you view quality.

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 18 output.mp4
```

> 3. "and convert the audio stream to 192k .mp3"

This can be interpreted two ways. Do you want the audio and video together in one output?

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k output.mp4
```

Or separate?

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0:v -c:v libx264 -crf 18 video.mp4 -map 0:a -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k audio.mp3
```

> 4. "Anyway, could you pls add a aac example together?"

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k output.mp4
```

### More info

- [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC Audio Encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)

Comment: But I still prefer 2 pass encoding. What I want is to re-encode the video that keep the original quality. I know that's a `copy` command that copy the codec, but it doesn't re-encode at all, it just mux the video with the encoded audio. Could you make changes on the command to re-encode the video that keep quality as much as possible, without spending much time(like `-preset veryslow` consume tons of time and power), and convert the audio stream to `192k .mp3`. Anyway, could you pls add a `aac` example together? Thanks.

Comment: @darkfang Why do you prefer 2-pass?

Comment: The output quality will be better than 1 pass

Comment: @darkfang [That is not true](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=143904). Anyway, answer updated.

Comment: Hmm.. I see. So tweaking the CRF value doesn't affect the bitrate?

Comment: @darkfang Changing the CRF value will change the bitrate. For example, a general assumption is that changing the CRF value +/-6 will result in about a 50% difference in bitrate.